# How do I find the probability that a Markov chain does or does not reach a state?

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

I have an ergodic Markov Chain with known probabilities, and I was trying to find the probability that the chain would reach a certain state after an n number of transitions. Is there any formula or general method to do so?

Likewise, is there a way to determine the probability that the chain will never reach a state after an $n$ number of transitions?

My attempts to find a solution did not yield any results, so any help for this questions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean after exactly $n$ transitions or at most $n$ transitions?  Both can be expressed with linear algebra.  Perhaps you can provide some details or an example and what you considered.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Readers will find it easier to respond in a way that helps you if you describe more fully your "attempts to find a solution".  Did you (for example) consider the case $n=1$? What might one do for $n=2$?  See [this introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to posting here with mathematical notation.